# VSCode intellisense and suggestions not working ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

My VScode intellisense and code suggestions stopped working.

This is what I did so far.

1. I cloned the project from github again
2. Removed VSCode, removed AppData\Roaming\Code and C:\Users\xxx.vscode
3. Reinstalled latest VSCode.

Still not working. It just say loading...

[image: VSCode intellisense not working]

Any way to make it work??

Comment: Do you get suggestions for other modules ?

Comment: Yes, this works fine for some other ReactJS projects, but not for others. Strange....

Comment: Looks like a bug with VSCode, I just downloaded the VSCode insider and it works fine... if anyone needs it this is the Insider download link https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

Comment: Switching to insider version fixed my Intellisense for a couple of minutes   I'm starting to think that my project (react-native) is too big for Intellisense to handle.